# How can I define custom Gestures on my touch screen windows laptop

Tags: windows-8.1, touchscreen, gestures

I want to define my own gestures on windows 8.1 on my Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro laptop. First of all, is this possible? and if it is, how can I do so?

For example I want to tell my laptop when I put five fingers on the touch screen, you open the OnScreenKeyboard.

Comment: [Customize Your Very Own Touchscreen Gestures On Your Windows 8 Device Using TouchMe Gesture Studio, It’s Awesome](http://microsoft-news.com/customize-your-very-own-touchscreen-gestures-on-your-windows-8-device-using-touchme-gesture-studio-its-awesome/)

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for the reply, I just couldn't find the download link.

Comment: I don't have Windows 8.1 but try http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/touchme-gesture-studio/740d3578-ddb4-4f74-b489-5a3782cb7607

Comment: Awesome software, unless you use the internet, specifically Chrome... 
http://www.yasharbahman.com/wp/a-crippling-chrome-issue/
...and it still crashes Chrome almost a year after coming out, sad!

Comment: Unfortunately the Microsoft Store is not available in my country. Is there no other way to define and use multi touch gestures? My touch-screen laptop can detect 10 fingers at the same time but there is no use for it, so why is that technology even produced? I want to bring on Virtual Keyboard when I press five fingers at the same time, but I can't. Touch screens are one of the most joyful one among late technologies, but no one seems to be willing to work on theme :(